# how to get data using date on my time stamp in SQL

Tags: php, mysql

My field name `time` and datatype is `timestamp`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    order_table
WHERE
    DATE(`time`) AS date_part = '2016-11-30';
```

Comment: the as date_part is invalid sql

Comment: why are you using alias in where condition ??

Comment: Whats the error? Remove PHP tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove alias from WHERE condition:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    order_table
WHERE
    DATE(time) = '2016-11-30';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use alias for your column then you can do this way:

```
SELECT
    *, time AS date_part
FROM
    order_table
WHERE
    DATE(time) = '2016-11-30';
```

It will add a new column to resultant array at last.

Answer (score 0):

use a query like this. do not use any function on a field value like **DATE(time)** . MySQL must calculate this for each row before it can compare. so MySQL cant use a index and you get a FULL TABLE SCAN

```
SELECT *
FROM order_table
WHERE `time` >= '2016-11-30 00:00:00'
AND   `time` <= '2016-11-30 23:59:59';
```